# How to implement video conferencing feature inside a website using webRTC?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, chat, webrtc

Recently I was working on a webRTC project that displays media stream in users browser. However this was only on the client side. What if I want to stream this media to other users browser. As I looked around I found that it was possible by connecting to peers and setting up signalling servers (STUN & TURN). I went through all details that was mentioned on one of the articles on **html5rocks** website.

I am making use of **simplewebRTC** but that isn't enough I have to set up my own signalling server in order to be actually able to video chat.

My question is what actually is needed in order to implement a live video chat application embedded within website apart from the api provided by webRTC and how do I set up my own signailling server.

Answer (score 1):

[signalmaster](https://github.com/andyet/signalmaster) was built as a signaling server for simplewebrtc and used by talky.io. It's a node application, start it with "node server.js" and then hook up simplewebrtc to the socket.io endpoint provided.

STUN and TURN servers are not signaling servers. They just help with punching a hole through NAT. The most popular option is [rfc-5766-turn-server](https://code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server/), [restund](https://github.com/otalk/restund) performs quite well too.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide more detail about your project to get a good answer.  Are you planning on making only browser to browser calls?  SIP calls?  These would be a factor in the signalling server you choose.  I went with a SIP signalling server (SIPML5.org) and integrated it with an Asterisk server for call control.  This also let me integrate my existing corporate telepresence devices into the PBX.  If you want to read up on the basics of signalling and on Webrtc in general Muaz Khan has done some very good work on it.

https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/blob/master/Signaling.md